# urllib2 and cookielib thread safety

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, urllib2

As far as I've been able to tell cookielib isnt thread safe; but then again the post stating so is five years old, so it might be wrong.

Nevertheless, I've been wondering - 
If I spawn a class like this:

```
class Acc:
    jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
    cookie = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar)       
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie)

    headers = {}
    def __init__ (self,login,password):
        self.user = login
        self.password = password

    def login(self):
        return False # Some magic, irrelevant

    def fetch(self,url):
        req = urllib2.Request(url,None,self.headers)
        res = self.opener.open(req)
        return res.read()
```

for each worker thread, would it work? (or is there a better approach?) Each thread would use it's own account; so the fact that workers wouldn't share their cookies is not a problem.

Comment: For reference, the post OP mentions is probably [this](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/40838-cookielib-urllib2-thread-safe) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) (the python interface to [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl)).  It's thread-safe, supports cookies, https, etc..  The interface is a bit strange, but it just takes a bit of getting used to.

I've only used pycurl w/ HTTPBasicAuth + SSL, but I did find an example using pycurl and cookies [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/267255-using-pycurl-to-automate-filling-out-web-forms/).  I believe you'll need to update the pycurl.COOKIEFILE (line 74) and pycurl.COOKIEJAR (line 82) to have some unique name (maybe keying off of `id(self.crl)`).

As I remember, you'll need to create a new `pycurl.Curl()` for each request to maintain thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

You could see implementation of the library `[python_install_path]/lib/cookielib.py` to ensure  that `cookielib.CookieJar` **is thread safe**.

It means if you will share one instance of `CookieJar` between several connections in different threads, you will not face even inconsistence read of Cookie Set, because `CookieJar` uses lock `self._cookies_lock` inside.

Answer (score 1):

the same question as you. If you do not use pycurl, I think you must urllib2.install_opener(self.opener) before each urllib2.urlopen.

Maybe I should use the pycurl too, urllib2 is not so smart.