# is multiprocessing.Connection thread safe?

Tags: python, thread-safety, multiprocessing

Is a `multiprocessing.Connection` python object thread safe?

If it is, two threads could simultaneously use `conn.recv()` and `conn.send()` on the same connection, which could be useful for full-duplex communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is **not** thread safe.  Up to Python 3.2, `multiprocessing.Connection` objects [do not have any semaphore attached](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3d0686d90f55/Modules/_multiprocessing/multiprocessing.h#l164), nor does any of the library code that uses them.

Interestingly, in Python 3.3 [the implementation has moved](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2f69db52d6de/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#l123).  But again, no locking primitive is beign used.

The documentation does not mention too much about the thread-safety of the `multiprocessing` module.  Which is a bit unexpected, given the quality of the Python documentation.

Comment: Which is expected, given the quality of the Python documentation. See [Are urllib2 and httplib thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825151/)