# Download many files in parallel? (Linux/Python?)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, download

I have a big list of remote file locations and local paths where I would like them to end up. Each file is small, but there are very many of them. I am generating this list within Python.

I would like to download all of these files as quickly as possible (in parallel) prior to unpacking and processing them. What is the best library or linux command-line utility for me to use? I attempted to implement this using multiprocessing.pool, but that did not work with the FTP library.

I looked into pycurl, and that seemed to be what I wanted, but I could not get it to run on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Your question says you're using Linux, but then you mention Windows 7, so which platform are you actually using, or do you need a cross-platform solution?

Comment: What was wrong with ftplib?

Answer (score 0):

Try [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), a command line utility installed on most Linux distros, also available via [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on Windows.

You may also have  a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), which is a library/framework written in Python.

Comment: In what sense is `wget` a perl utility?

Comment: It's written in Perl, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm, for a reason I was thinking it was a Perl program, sorry about that. I'm deleting 'Perl' from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `pscp` to do things like this, and then call it using `subprocess.Popen`

for example:

```
pscp_command = '''"c:\program files\putty\pscp.exe" -pw <pwd> -p -scp -unsafe <file location on my   linux machine including machine name and login, can use wildcards here> <where you want the files to go on a windows machine>'''
p = subprocess.Popen( pscp_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
p.wait()
```

of course I'm assuming linux --> windows

Answer (score 0):

If youuse a `Pool` object from the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module, `urllib2` should handle FTP.

```
results = {}
def get_url(url):
    try:
        res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        # url should start with 'ftp:'
        results[url] = res.read()
    except Exception:
        # add more meaningful exception handling if you need it. Eg, retry once etc. 
        results[url] = None
pool = Pool(processes=num_processes)
result = pool.map_async(get_url, url_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Of course, spawning processes will have some serious overhead. Non-blocking requests will almost certainly be faster if you can use a 3rd part module like [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/)

Whether the overhead is a serious problem will depend on the relative magnitude of download times per file and network latency.

You can try implementing it using python threads rather than processes, but it gets a bit trickier. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825151/are-urllib2-and-httplib-thread-safe) to use urllib2 safely with threads. You would also need to use the `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` instead of the regular `Pool`

Answer (score 0):

Know it's an old post but there is a perfect linux utility for this. If you are transferring files from a remote host, `lftp` is great! I mainly use it to quickly push stuff to my ftp server but it works great for pulling stuff off as well using the `mirror` command. It also has an option to copy a user defined number of files in parallel like you wanted. If you wanted to copy some files from a remote path to a local path your command line would look something like this;

```
lftp
open ftp://user:password@ftp.site.com
cd some/remote/path
lcd some/local/path
mirror --reverse --parallel=2
```

Be very careful with this command though, just like other mirror commands if you screw it up, you WILL DELETE FILES.

For more options or documentation for `lftp` I've visited this site http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html